# Como recuperar dados de um form HTML aberto em uma WebView?

Tags: php, java, html, android, mysql

Olá! Eu tenho uma aplicação web responsiva que eu pretendo abrir via aplicativo android através de uma WebView. Pois bem, o único problema é que eu precisaria pegar alguns dados do submit de somente um form da aplicação para enviar para uma impressora bluetooth(cujo código é baseado em java). Tem como eu pegar esses dados que vem da aplicação web e passar para o meu aplicativo java? Quanto mais simples melhor. Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 2):

Você precisa adicionar uma interface, na hora que declara o webView.

Exemplo:

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
```

Código da classe **WebAppInterface**:

```
public class WebAppInterface {
    Context mContext;

    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    WebAppInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    /** Show a toast from the web page */
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showToast(String toast) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Agora no seu PHP, você deve incluir o onClick no seu input.

Exemplo:

```
<input type="button" value="Say hello" onClick="showAndroidToast('Hello Android!')" />
```

E o JavaScript que será responsável por "conversar" com o Android:

Exemplo:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showAndroidToast(toast) {
        Android.showToast(toast);
    }
</script>
```

Você pode ver mais exemplos e detalhes na [documentação do Android](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#BindingJavaScript)

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, bem interessante porém não ficou claro pra mim como eu posso passar os dados do form através do onClick do botão submit e recuperá-los no Java. Agradeceria imensamente se fosse possível compartilhar um exemplo.